# git svn clone: Error from SVN, (220001): Item is not readable

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I got this error when trying to build a git repo from remote svn server, it seems many people encountered this with different cause. All the google results didn't work for me, I just fixed the error with fuzzy solution.

Error:

> git svn fetch
>
> W: Item is not readable at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/perl/Git/SVN.pm line 154.
>
> Error from SVN, (220001): Item is not readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The key target is not git-svn but svn.**

I checked the svn permission with command **svn list** and got permission denied error, then specified argument "--username myname" and "--config-dir ." for list command, after svn saved my svn config in somewhere, run the "git svn clone repo_url", it works!

I fixed this error by chance, here is my guess, git-svn invoked the svn command in its internal implementation from file "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/perl/Git/SVN.pm line 154", so svn must have sufficient permissions to checkout the repo.

I didn't find the exact answer, just share my code experience here.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

[Git svn does not use the svn credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549463/git-svn-does-not-use-the-svn-credentials/44641961#44641961)

It may be credential problem -- The .subversion folder cannot provide credential. See my answer, it may help.

> The reason why git-svn does not use SVN is that it use the credentials
>   stored at C:\Users\XXXX.subversion, which is created by git-svn but
>   not SVN. In my case, **Error from SVN, (220001): Item is not readable:
>   Item is not readable** also occur.
>
> The solution is to move the credentials from SVN to git-svn:
>
> 1. Use SVN to check out from server. Remember to save auth. This can create credentials for SVN. The files are stored at
>      C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Subversion.
> 2. Remove the .subversion folder which is under user directory C:\Users\XXXXX if it exists. And then copy the
>      C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Subversion folder to C:\Users\XXXXX.
> 3. Then rename it to .subversion. Since the name starts with a ".", you may need to rename it in cmd console with "rename" command.
> 4. Finally, you can use git-svn clone.

Comment: This clear and easy answer worked perfectly for me. I recommend using this one.

Answer (score 1):

That is due to lack of permission. On your SVN server open the "authz" file located at config directory of the repository. Add the following line to allow read-only access to every one:

[/]
* = r

You may want to revoke the access after you finished the migration.

Comment: There is a bug in apache server 1.14.2. Daniel B.'s solution (* = r, then revoke the access afterwards) fixes the problem. But only for client A. Not for client B, etc. You have to do same on-then-off for him. This means there is a bug in the authorizing server code. This sounds like an uninitialized variable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but in my case it was not caused by missing permissions, but the fact that git-svn has created and used its own `.subversion` configuration folder under `%USERPROFILE%`, while svn was using `Subversion` folder under `%APPDATA%`.

My solution was deleting the `.subversion` folder from `%USERPROFILE%` and creating in its place a symlink (named `.subversion`) that points to svn configuration directory `%APPDATA%\Subversion`.

Answer (score 0):

if the aliases section is missing in the authz config file this happens