# Git svn does not use the svn credentials

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, git-svn

I try to clone a path from our svn repository. The repository is secured with passwords.

I have found some subversion directories on my Windows 10 System and created symlinks for them. So it is only one directory.

I opened the git-bash and started the command

```
svn checkout --username myuser --password mypassword svn://myserver/myrepository/myproject/trunk
```

SVN created in the auth/svn.simple directory a file with my credentials. The file starts with

```
K 8
passtype
V 8
wincrypt
K 8
password
...
```

The following command is now succesful:

```
svn update trunk
```

Now I want to use git-svn:

```
git svn clone svn://myserver/myrepository/myproject --username myuser
```

But all I get is the following response:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/mylocalprojectpath/.git/
W: Item is not readable: Item is not readable at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 153.
**Error from SVN, (220001): Item is not readable: Item is not readable**
```

All I have found about this error says that this is an authentication problem. So it seems to me that git svn does not use the stored credentials of svn.

What am I doing wrong? Some suggestions?

Comment: Is this about a one-time migration and you only want to use Git afterwards, or do you want to commit back to the SVN repository from the Git clone?

Comment: Hi, I want to use the SVN repository from the Git clone.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why git-svn does not use SVN is that it use the credentials stored at C:\Users\XXXX.subversion, which is created by git-svn but not SVN.
In my case, **Error from SVN, (220001): Item is not readable: Item is not readable** also occur.

The solution is to move the credentials from SVN to git-svn:

1. Use SVN to check out from server. Remember to save auth. This can create credentials for SVN. The files are stored at C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Subversion.
2. Remove the .subversion folder which is under user directory C:\Users\XXXXX if it exists. And then copy the C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Subversion folder to C:\Users\XXXXX.
3. Then rename it to .subversion. Since the name starts with a ".", you may need to rename it in cmd console with "rename" command.
4. Finally, you can use git-svn clone.

Comment: @Gerard I think I answer the question. The issue is about git-svn clone fail. I met the issue too. And it is caused by the git-svn credentials problem. The solution is apply original SVN credentials to git-svn credentials.