# "git svn init" hangs and does not create valid repo

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

`git svn init <https://...> -T trunk -b branches -t tags --username <login>` outputs

```
Initialized empty Git repository in <path>
```

and then it always hangs. The created `.git` directory is configured incorrectly, in particular, the `.git\config` file is missing the `[svn]` section with paths to trunk and branches directories. Even when I fill in the `.git\config` manually, the subsequent `git fetch` hangs again. I suspect this might be caused by the wrong authentication?

Concerning the authentication, I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/44641961/1259360, and it seems to me that `git` actually reads these copied credentials.

**Edit:** Concerning possible duplicate questions: They are related to `fetch`, not `init`, which assumes the git repo has been already created.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Windows 7 Pro x64, Git for Windows v2.20.1 (Dec 2018)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "git svn fetch" command seem to be stuck and does nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878976/why-does-git-svn-fetch-command-seem-to-be-stuck-and-does-nothing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-svn%5D+fetch+hangs

Comment: Especially see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54910767/7976758

Comment: Unfortunately, I can access the repo only via HTTPS, and username@ does not work for this access method. The other referred defects do not seem relevant to me, there the hanging occurs in later operations, not at the very beginning ("init"). I have already seen and tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878976/why-does-git-svn-fetch-command-seem-to-be-stuck-and-does-nothing, but this didn't work either - .metadata file isn't created in my repo.

Comment: After reinstallation of git, username@ works iven for https.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work! Though I do not know exactly what was the fix, I made the following:

- I re-installed git to a slightly newer version (from 2.20.1 to 2.21.0). Though it is possible that the previous version had this particular problem with `git svn`, it's improbable.
- I re-installed git with the option "use OpenSSH", originally there was "use TortoisePlink". I think that this change made it working.

I didn't re-install it again to investigate the real cause.